# Build web app functionality behind an Api

Tags: php, rest, web-services, web, architecture

I have to prepare a specification to provide a road-map for developers to build an in-house project.
The project will consist of a web application and a mobile application.
The mobile app will be used to collect user feedback, typically the mobile app shall display a couple of questions for the user to answer.

Example questions show below;

1. Did you use shoe polish to clean your shoes ?
2. Did you watch the news at night ?

The data captured will be sent to an sql server.

The web app shall be used to publish the questions to the mobile app, the web app shall also be used to view reports.
The web app shall have below features;
1.  Publish surveys to the mobile app, this could be done by MQTT,AMQP or similar protocol.
2.  View data in chart form
3.  Manage devices, like enrolling new mobile devices e.t.c

What is needed 
This project will be spit and assigned to 3 teams, the backend team(Api team) , the frontEnd team and the Mobile developers team.
The functionality of the backend is supposed to go into an Api, the front end should always talk to the backend for getting data, basically no business logic is allowed to go into the front end side of things. The front end will only write css/html/js for markup & presentation, the rest of the functionality should be consumed through an Api.

I have to write a detailed specification of how the project should be implemented, the back-end will be implemented in PHP with symphony. The front-end can be any JavaScript framework, the mobile app will be implemented in Android.

Can you should how i should model the back-End(Api) so that it contains all the functionality needed in the web app ?
On top of that, building the functionality on top of an api a good strategy for this project? Should i go the monolithic way as having the front end and back-End attached together(this will make it difficult to have one developer working on the front end and another one on the back-End/api ) ?

Comment: you simply need to write centralised API which will be consumed by your both parties Front-end and Mobile.
Your Front-end Php can use curl to post and receive data from API server and fetch or other can be used by mobile side to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect application for a CQRS back end, fed by a queue.  With CQRS the write side and read side of the back end are separated into distinct APIs which is especially advantageous when splitting a project among multiple teams.

The main idea of CQRS is that there is a single API to make any changes to data, and changes are made to data via a Command, then persisted to the normalized DB by the Command.  There are also physical tables custom designed to contain all data necessary for a single view (these tables are denormalized).  Each time data is written to an Aggregate, the appropriate View Models are also updated.  This results in a structure where the write side is complicated but has all business logic and rules, whereas the read side is very simple and basically just executes a “select *” query from the appropriate view model table.  As long as the read model (also called a projection) is kept up to date the reads are much faster and since the majority of the DB access is reads, the entire site is faster.

In your case I would create 3 APIs – one for the Read Model for the Mobile front end, one for the Read Model for the web front end, and one for the Command side.  That way the mobile guys have the flexibility to build what they need, and they can change the read model table design as necessary during development to satisfy requirements.  The Web guys can do the same, and the Backend team implements the hard stuff – the commands, business rules, normalized table structures, etc.  Merging the three projects would entail having one of the teams create queries to update the view model tables from the entity tables.

All this becomes even easier if you introduce an event based communication architecture, i.e. Event Driven Architecture.  This would further decouple the 3 different concerns and make them even easier to merge later since each microservice would subscribe to appropriate messages to receive updates and new cache information.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Irby , very clear explanation about CQRS. I'll read more about it and possibly use the architecture in my project.